# class object equals class pointer object with templates

Tags: c++, templates

I don't know a question for my C++ course.

```
template <typename T> class Array {...};
void main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

Array<int> *a1 = new Array<int>();
Array<int> a2();
a2 = *a1; // <--  
}
```

What will happen at the noted line (<--)?
a) a2 copy constructor is called.
b) The address of a2 becomes equal to the address of pointer a1.
c) copy assignment operator of a2 is called
d) compilation error

Justify your answer.

Comment: Justify your question.

Comment: You know you could write the code run it and find out.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 1):

d) compilation error as you have vexing parse:

```
Array<int> a2(); // Declaration of function which takes no argument and return Array<int>
```

Comment: @TartanLlama My bad.  You are correct.  It also will generate an error/warning since main is declared as `void`